# Why does this macro break with Lastpage?

Tags: macros, page-numbering, lastpage

I have made a macro `\@Romankern` that makes roman numerals with a negative kerning between them to make them closer to each other. I named it `\@Romankern` to allow it to be used with `\pagenumbering`.

The macro works fine until I load the `lastpage` package. When this package is loaded the macro breaks telling me:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@Romankern #1->\edef \temp 
                            {\@Roman {#1}}\expandafter \@romkern \temp ...
```

I tried to trace the source of the error but failed... miserably. What is wrong with my macro that it is so fragile?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\makeatletter

\def\@Romankern#1{%
  \edef\temp{\@Roman{#1}}%
  \expandafter\@romkern\temp\@empty}
\def\@romkern#1#2{%
  \ifx#2\@empty
    #1%
    \let\next\relax
  \else
    #1\kern-0.07em%
    \let\next\@romkern
  \fi
  \next#2}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Romankern}

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of `\@Romankern` is not robust, because it contains assignments (`\def\temp{...}`, `\let\next\@romkern`, ...). If the label is written to the `.aux` file, assignments are not carried out and `\def\temp{...}` becomes to something like `\def<the expansion of \temp>{...}` with `<the expansion of \temp>` being the result of expanding the current meaning of `\temp`. In the case of the question `\temp` is undefined and therefore raises an error.

The following example defines a macro `\@@Romankern` that takes a plain number as argument and that will go to the `.aux` file. The conversion of the argument of `\@Romankern`, a counter value, to a plain number is done in an expandable and therefore robust way (via `\expandafter` and `\number`). The macro `\@@Romankern` is made robust by e-TeX's `\protected` that prevents the expansion of `\@@Romankern`, when writing to the `.aux` file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\makeatletter
\def\@Romankern#1{%
  \expandafter\@@Romankern\expandafter{\number#1}%
}
\protected\def\@@Romankern#1{%
  \edef\temp{\@Roman{#1}}%
  \expandafter\@romkern\temp\@empty\@empty
}
\def\@romkern#1#2{%
  \ifx#2\@empty
    #1%
    \let\next\relax
  \else
    #1\kern-0.07em%
    \let\next\@romkern
  \fi
  \next#2}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Romankern}

Last page: \pageref{LastPage}

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

The `.aux` file contains:

```
\relax
\newlabel{LastPage}{{}{\@@Romankern {10}}}
\xdef\lastpage@lastpage{\@@Romankern {10}}
\gdef\lastpage@lastpageHy{}
```

**Remarks:**

- The call of `\@romkern` in

  ```
  \def\temp{\@Roman{#1}}%
  \expandafter\@romkern\temp\@empty\@empty
  ```

  is modified to contain *two* stop tokens `\@empty`, because `\@romkern` always expects *two* arguments. But `\temp` is empty for zero or negative numbers.

Comment: Ooh, now I understand it. Excellent explanation. Thanks a lot :)